# Como Llenar un Spinner con Volley y obtener un id

Tags: android-studio

Hola Amigos como indicaba estoy tratando de llenar un spinner en android studio , que consume este servicio REST :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "idDistrito": 1,
            "descripcion": "Lima"
        },
        {
            "idDistrito": 2,
            "descripcion": "Santa ANita"
        }
    ]
}
```

... Lo que pasa es que quiero que en mi spinner salga la "descripcion" y al momento que le de click tome el valor de su id ("idDistrito").

¿Alguien me podría ayudar ? por favor?

Este es mi código :

String

`URL="http://192.168.43.164:8080/WsAlpacaNativa/Distrito/ListarComboDistrito/";`

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);

                    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String cod=jsonObject1.getString("idDistrito");
                        String des=jsonObject1.getString("descripcion");
                        CountryName.add(cod +"-"+des);
                    }                   
              spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, CountryName));
            }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Se llena el spinner? solo te falta capturar el id?

Comment: Igmer Rodriguez , si men osea si llena el Spinner , pero con el codigo que tengo el spinner sale algo como : "1 - Lima" , "2- Santa Anita" , pero lo que quiero es seleccionar la descripción  y obtener el valor del id , Por ejemplo Selecciono 'Lima' y un Toast me aparezca ´1´ , para despues tomar ese 1 y guardarla en la base de datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que tu lista es una ArrayList podrias hacer los asi:

```
spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String fila = CountryName.get(position);
            String[] parts = fila.split("-");
            String id = parts[0];

        }
    });
```

Si tuvieras una lista de objetos seria un poco mas limpio y mas facil pero de esta forma funciona.

Comment: Si Igmer Rodriguez GRACIAS, logré a obtener el ID , Pero con eso al momento de Listar mi Spinner Sale algo como   "1-Lima" , como haría para que solo me muestre la Descripcion y me capture el ID ?

Comment: si tienes log get y set de tu clase puedes crear una lista de objetos luego con tus datos, luego recorrer esa lista de objetos para crear tu arrayList en el onItemClick ir a buscar a tu lista de objetos ese ID

Comment: Gracias Igmer Rodriguez , Se me salio :) Muchas Gracias Amigo :D